# REACT- Redirection Link not working and applying filters on table

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, react-hooks, data-extraction

I have my table that displays all the id and title of my menu (1) (see menus.json). I want to add an hyperlink to my title but it doesn't work:

```
{
    Header: "Title",
    // accessor: "title"
    accessor: (row) => row.title,
    // Link the content of my cell. NOT WORKING 
    Cell: ({ row }) => (
      <Link to={{ pathname: `/menu/${row.id}` }}>{row.title}</Link>
    )
}
```

By clicking on my title name,ex Menu1 (1),  it will redirect me to a new page with a table that contains all the names of the menus that match my id_menu (2) .

Here the sandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-tree-ggwuty?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Cell` appears to used for formatting of a value. `accessor` property is only telling the hook how to access and read values from your data.

> - Cell: `Function | React.Component => JSX`
>
>   - Optional
>   - Defaults to `({ value }) => String(value)`
>   - Receives the table instance and cell model as props
>   - Must return valid JSX
>   - ***This function (or component) is primarily used for formatting the column value, eg. If your column accessor returns a date object, you can use a `Cell` function to format that date to a readable format.***

Emphasis is mine.

Use the `accessor` property to read the row value and return the value you want to access in the `Cell` function. You can either return the entire `row` value, or create a new object with the specific properties you want to use to render. In the `Cell` function access the `value` property and return the JSX, i.e. computed `Link` component.

```
const data = useMemo(
  () => [
    {
      Header: "Id",
      // accessor: "id"
      accessor: (row) => row.id
    },
    {
      Header: "Title",
      // accessor: "title"
      accessor: (row) => ({ title: row.title, id: row.id }),
      Cell: ({ value }) => (
        <Link to={{ pathname: `/menu/${value.id}` }}>{value.title}</Link>
      )
    }
  ],
  []
);
```

You will need to also import and use a router component and create routes to render each different table you want to render (*i.e. one for each view you shared*).

For the purpose of getting the *existing* `Link` you were trying to use working I only wrapped the `Display` component in a `BrowserRouter`. You'll need to create the routes you actually want to render different table content into.

[image: Edit react-redirection-link-not-working-and-applying-filters-on-table]

[image: clicking "chicken tenders" navigates to "/menu/Menu2"]

Build out routes for each table you want to display.

Example:

App

```
<Router>
  <Routes>
    <Route path="/menu" element={<Display />} />
    <Route path="/menu/:menuId" element={<MenuDisplay />} />
    <Route path="*" element={<Navigate to="/menu" replace />} />
  </Routes>
</Router>
```

MenuDisplay

```
function MenuDisplay() {
  const { menuId } = useParams();
  const { match } = JsonData;

  const matchData = match.find((el) => el._id_menu === menuId)?._ids ?? [];

  const data = useMemo(
    () => [
      {
        Header: "Name",
        accessor: (row) => row.name
      },
      {
        Header: "Description",
        accessor: (row) => row.description
      },
      {
        Header: "Dishes",
        accessor: (row) => row.dishes,
        Cell: ({ value }) => Object.values(value[0]).join(", ")
      }
    ],
    []
  );

  const initialState = {
    sortBy: [
      { desc: false, id: "id" },
      { desc: false, id: "description" },
      { desc: false, id: "dishes" }
    ]
  };

  return (
    <Table
      data={matchData}
      columns={data}
      initialState={initialState}
      withCellBorder
      withRowBorder
      withSorting
      withPagination
    />
  );
}
```

[image: Edit react-redirection-link-not-working-and-applying-filters-on-table (forked)]

Comment: Thank you !  Do I really have to "_render each different table you want to render (i.e. one for each view you shared)_". Can I have a Component called Match that displays all the menus names and when I'm selecting Menu1 I display the respective menus and hide the others ? I can do what you say if I get 3 pages but if I have more. Do you think is it possible to do ?

Comment: @Zokulko IMO you will want a different "Display" component for each different table layout. For example, this initial table layout appears to be a "Menus" table, and the second table layout appears to be a "Menu Detail" table, rendering entirely different row data/columns. Does this make sense?

Comment: @Zokulko The alternative is you have just the one `Display` component that needs to account for all the different URLs and path params and create all the different memoized `data` objects for a table... creating what I call "giant monolithic" components can get quite messy and unmanageable very quickly. I view and approach React component development with the [Single Responsibility Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-responsibility_principle) where each component does one thing and does it well. Consider these as building blocks of your app, composing them together to build the UI.

Comment: The penultimate comment seems to be more realisable for me to begin... Your last comment is very interesting but I don't know if I'll manage to do it

Comment: I've tried your last comment but I'm a bit lost really don't know how to manage all these things

Comment: @Zokulko Do you just need a small demo?

Comment: Yes please  just to the render for one menu. Because it's very vague

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243833/discussion-between-drew-reese-and-zokulko).